# Return a pair - syntax error

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, racket

I'm using `pl` in racket: https://pl.barzilay.org/
The download can be found here: http://pl.barzilay.org/pl.plt

```
( : f1 : -> (Pairof Symbol String))
(define (f1)
  (cons 'wwww "aaa"))
```

Error:

```
   Type Checker: Polymorphic function `cons' could not be applied to arguments:
Argument 1:
  Expected: a
  Given:    'wwww
Argument 2:
  Expected: (Listof a)
  Given:    String

Result type:     (Listof a)
Expected result: (Pairof Symbol String)
 in: (cons (quote wwww) "aaa")
```

What I did wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the type of `cons` as defined in the language `pl`? If `cons` has the type `(Pairof a (Listof a))` then the second argument "aaa" in your example will not be accepted by the type checker.

Comment: I couldn't find the specification of `pl` but I saw that `(cons 1 2 )` does not compile also, so I guess that you are right. Due to the fact that there is no documentation and there is only one guy in the world who can formally answer this question, I guess it's ok that you answer it and we close this issue.

Comment: You could ask Eli :-)

Comment: haha... I already emailed him so let's see if he will answer in the mail and if yes, I will forward the answer to here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#lang pl` language that I use in my class is a variant of Typed
Racket.  One of the changes it has is that `cons` has a more restricted
type (as you've seen) which allows it to only construct *proper lists*.

(As a sidenote, the reason there is no formal documentation is that this
language is intended to be used in the class, and as such it's something
that is subject to random pedagogic needs and not as something to be
used for random Racket code...  So my class notes are the main place
that "documents" the language.)