# can not use list functions on an input var - racket

Tags: list, racket

well after building a whole function I got many problems and now I am breaking it down into small parts.

My func gets two vars one is a list and the other is a pair. When using **(first var1)** I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
#lang pl

    (define (maxMin list maxiMini)
      (if (null? maxiMini)
          (first list)
          2
      )
    )
```

Here is the error:

> Type Checker: Polymorphic function `first' could not be applied to
>   arguments:
>
> Domains: (Listof a)
>
> ```
>         (Pairof a (Listof b))
> ```
>
> Arguments: Any
>
> in: (first list)

While in this youtube tutorial at minute 1 and 10 seconds the professor uses the first function the same way as me and it does work there.

My guess is that Racket does not recognize myList as a list and sets it as "any" is this possible?

Comment: Although you have not provided sufficient information and a proper minimal example for your problem, I guess your code suffers from a _name clash_ with Racket's `list`. Just rename the `list` variable in your function definition with something like `lst` or `list$`. See if the problem is solved.

Comment: @AlQuemist Hey, I actually tried this and named it MyList. Regarding the insufficient amount of data, I put in my whole code. What else can I put in to help? The only part I left out was the sublanguage.

Comment: could you please add a simple use-case of your function? I cannot figure out the type of `maxMini`. Is it a `list` or a `pair`? If it is meant to be a `pair`, then why do you apply `null?` to it? We cannot make an empty `pair` in Racket; see eg., the [Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html).

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks for your time, @assefamaru answered but you also helped me! Yes, I didn't give the context of a use case since this was a small part of a larger program. Also, I checked if it null since I didn't know it can't be, so thanks for teaching me this!

Comment: Perhaps, one should simply use `#lang racket`, not Typed Racket, for such exercises; why do you use Typed Racket?

Comment: Well, I use it because that's what the professor asked us. He explained why he asked us to do so but I don't remember why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a Type Checker error, I assume you're using either `#lang typed/racket`, or some variant of it.

If you look closely at the error itself, it is telling you that `first` is a *polymorphic* function, meaning that it can be applied to arguments of different types. Furthermore, the error also states the different types the function `first` expects under "Domains:", ie. its argument should either be `(Listof a)` or `(Pairof a (Listof b))`.

The problem is, you've not actually defined a type for your function `maxMin`. And if a type annotation is omitted, the inferred type is often `Any`. As a result, your function does not type-check, because `first` does not expect the type `Any` and that's what it is getting.

Since you stated

> My func gets two vars one is a list and the other is a pair

consider the following type annotation for your function:

```
(: max-min (-> (Listof Any) (U Null (Pairof Any Any)) Any))
(define (max-min lst maxi-mini)
  (if (null? maxi-mini)
      (first lst)
      2))
```

which will type-check, and you can have:

```
(max-min '(1 2 3) '())
=> 1
```

Comment: Hi can you explain me this part: "...(U Null (Pairof Any Any)) Any))"

Comment: [`U`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html?q=U#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._.U%29%29) is a union of types. If an argument has type `(U a b c)`, then its value can only be one of type a, b, or c. So, in the above case, the type restricts `maxi-mini` to either be null or a pair.

Comment: But note that `#lang pl` has a more [restricted cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465474/return-a-pair-syntax-error/49498145#49498145) that only creates "proper lists". As such, a more appropriate type for your function will probably be `(: max-min (-> (Listof Any) (Listof Any) Any))`. If you know you will only be dealing with numbers, you can make the types even more specific: `(: max-min (-> (Listof Number) (Listof Number) Number))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you really helped me! Last question: why did you write an extran Number at the end (-> (Listof Number) (Listof Number) ??Number??))

Comment: The last `Number` is the type of the function's result. You can rewrite it as: `(: max-min : (Listof Number) (Listof Number) -> Number)`. Have a quick read [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/beginning.html).